# What's the penalty for dying in Bioshock Infinite?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

I feel like when I die and come back from the reload point, the number of silver eagles that I find in drawers and barrels is less.  I'm wondering if this is an actual penalty for dying, or if it's just all in my head.

**What are the penalties for dying in Bioshock Infinite?**  If it is different for the different difficulties, please list them out.

Comment: The finding less bit is in your head. The "of course I died 15 times after finding a couple hundred silver eagles" bit is not. That is conspiracy. Or me not being smart enough to backtrack when I have an amount of money.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The amount of money you lose when you die depends on the difficulty level.

- **Easy**: (Unknown)
- **Medium**: (Unknown)
- **Hard**: 50 Silver Eagles.
- **1999 Mode**: 100 Silver Eagles.

In 1999 Mode, it's **game over** if you die with no money. You must reload the game from the most recent autosave.

On easier difficulties, if you can't pay the death penalty, you are simply resurrected normally.

Comment: You sure it's only 50 on Hard?

Comment: @DoozerBlake I'm 90% sure...but now I'm in the middle of another playthrough in 1999 Mode and can't reload an old Hard mode save to confirm without wiping my current one. Grr.

Comment: You were right, I guess it seemed like more when I was dying, but did confirm the amount on Hard is 50.

Comment: Its also good to note that falling off of Columbia does not count as dying, as you just instantly respawn, it is only if you die by draining health.

Comment: does the (Unknown) for medium and easy mean that you are unaware of the amount, or does it mean that the amount changes each time?

Comment: @PileOfDuty I've never played on those difficulties so I simply don't know. Feel free to edit the actual number in if you do! :)

Answer (score 1):

When you die, you lose some of the money that you have and any enemies that you were fighting at the time recover some of their health. This effect is more pronounced at higher difficulties.